# Fail webpack build when plugin throws an error

Tags: webpack

How do I make my webpack build fail if `scripts.js` throws an error? Adding `--bail` as a flag or as a configuration option does not work.

```
// webpack.config.js
const SynchronizableShellPlugin = require('webpack-synchronizable-shell-plugin');

...

bail: true, // this does not work like I expect it to
plugins: {
  new SynchronizableShellPlugin({
    onBuildStart: {
      scripts: ['node script.js'],
      blocking: true
    }
  }),
}

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this specific plugin does not throw an error in case of script failure. You can use different plugin, e.g. [pre-build-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-build-webpack).